What is the nature of the pole of the derivative of $\frac{1}{1- \ln(x)}$ at $x=0$?
I'm interested in the function $\frac{1}{1-\ln(x)}$ on positive real line.
One can experimentally see that
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \left[ x \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{1}{1 - \ln(x)} \right] \right] = 0 $$
Yet also
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \left[ \frac{1}{\ln(x)} \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{1}{1 - \ln(x)} \right] \right] = \infty $$
This real singularity exhibits behavior weaker than a simple pole of order 1 yet stronger than the singularity of $\ln(x)$.
I was wondering if anyone has articulated exactly what the nature of this singularity is. I suspect the answer lies in the following set. Let us declare the set of "order functions". $f(x) = x$ is such a function. If $u$ is an order function then $u^a$ for any real number $r$ is an order function. If $u$ is an order function then $\log^{q} (u)$ is an order function where $q$ refers to real-valued fractional iteration. Ex $\log^{-1}(u) = e^{u}$. Now I believe there SHOULD exist a finite formula order function $T(x)$ that:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \left[ T(x) \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{1}{1 - \ln(x)} \right] \right] = c $$
For some constant $c$. I'm not sure how to find it though and would be curious if anyone else has a better grasp on this problem (And/or can relate it nontrivially to the real singularity of any other real valued function).

$\dfrac{1}{1-\ln(x)}$ does not have a pole at $x=0$, as its limit is finite and equal to $0$.

Yes this is correct however its derivative at $0$ appears to be infinite. It’s not a normal place, and I’m trying to tame it in terms of familiar objects. I can see that the derivative lives between $\ln$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ possibly inclusively.

So you are referring to the pole of the derivative of that function at $x=0$? In that case, the title is a bit misleading

I guess that’s fair. I have edited my title to make it clearer exactly what I mean.

The derivative is $\frac{1}{x(1- \log x)^2}$ which as $x \to 0$ behaves as $\frac{1}{x \log^2 x}$ Doesn't this answer your qustion ?

That certainly does. I am silly I should have tried to differentiating this symbolically and staring at it. Please do post as an answer so I can give you the credit you are due.

Let $g(x)$ the derivative, then
$$g(x) =\frac{1}{x(1- \log x)^2}$$
When $x\to 0$ the leading term is $$\frac{1}{x \log^2 x}$$
